# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - except the class exists

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using NetBeans IDE to code my Java program. A few days ago, I had it working the way I wanted to. Now that I opened it again to add some changes and comments, this **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** popped up suddenly. I have searched around but I can't seem to find a proper answer. I have set my **CLASSPATH** to my Java folder (*C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin*) but it still won't work. I'm thinking of copying and pasting all my codes in a different directory but I'm afraid that the problem would still happen in the future, and changing the project's location would be too much of a hassle once the program gets really big.

In my program, I have **two classes** (**Word** and **Dictionary**) and a JFrame form (**MainForm**). Inside the **Dictionary** class, I have a function called **testDictionary** that inserts dummy data (ten **Word** objects) into the **Dictionary** object. This was running a few days ago, with no error whatsoever, but when I ran the program today, it stops on the line that says:

```
Word myWord = new Word();
```

and the **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** appears. Please help me resolve this issue, in case it appears in the future again. Thank you very much. :)

**EDIT:**
I have already fixed this by going to

**Run > Clean and Build Main Project (Shift + F11)**

then I tested it again and it worked. Though I still don't know how to ACTUALLY solve the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to recompile?

Comment: Yes, perhaps you disabled auto-compile?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have not touched any settings in NetBeans ever since I've installed and used it, so I don't know how AutoCompile would have been disabled (I don't even know how to turn it off).

Comment: Oh, it's fixed now. I went to Run > Clean and Build Main Project then I  went to Run > Run Main Project again. I was worried it wouldn't be solved.

Comment: Lance Gray: can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already fixed this by going to

**Run > Clean and Build Main Project (Shift + F11)**